# Precision or Recall when dealing with critical cases?

Tags: image-classification

I have to create an AI that classifies mutliple objects in order to accept them or not inside a machine.
The problem is that some objects could be really harmful to the machine if they get accepted.

Should I focus on an high Precision or an high Recall, in order to not accept this kind of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say your target variable "1" represents "Harmful Object".

Precision answers the question - Of all objects predicted as Harmful - How many are really harmful ?

Recall answers the question - Of all the Harmful objects out there - How many were correctly identified ?

You want to increase on Recall in your case - since that reduces the overall risk to the machine.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's clear now

Comment: Please accept it as the correct answer if you are satisfied with the response.